# Find $f$ such that the contraction $\phi$ has a fixed-point $\rho= \sqrt{2}$

Tags: analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

I use the Newton method and the Banach fixed-point theorem and have:

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ a closed interval and $\phi: I \rightarrow I$ Lipschitz continous and  $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a function.

I know, that

\begin{equation}
\phi(x_n) = x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}
\end{equation}

Now I want to find an $f$ such that the contraction $\phi$ has a fixed-point $\rho= \sqrt{2}$

Are there many $f$ or is there only one $f$ which I can use? I just do not know how to start.

Answer (score 2):

Try with $$
f(x) = \frac 12 \left(
x + \frac 2x
\right)
$$

This is not Lipschitz on $(0,\infty)$ but on any $[a,\infty)$.
It remains to prove that $x$ is bounded from below to conclude with the theorem.

Comment: How can I prove that $x$ is bounded from below? Can I say that for $x_0 >> 0$ contract to $\sqrt{2}$? Is that enough?